# Azure - Origem de gravação de BLOB em camada Quente

Tags: microsoft-azure, blob

Senhores tudo bem?

Na minha conta Azure está exibindo um alto consumo de: "Operações de Gravação de LRS Quente - Blob de Bloco em Camadas - 192% 1,92 / 1 10K" imagem a seguir:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nos últimos 3 dias esse número que nunca passou de 0% passou a subir exponencialmente e gostaria de entender a origem, mas não consigo identificar.

Conferi nas áreas de upload de minha aplicação e usando a ferramenta do "Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer" meus blobs estão todos em camada Fria, não houve gravação em camada quente.

O que fiz de diferente nestes últimos dias:

1. Habilitar logs de query lenta no MySql
2. No meu Web App fiz cache em arquivos que usa o armazenamento alocado no "Plano de Serviços"
3. Habilitei alguns webJobs que simplesmente fazem uma chamada para meu App, não mexe com armazenamento tais operações
4. Tenho 4 Web Apps no mesmos Plano de serviços, somente 1 tem log habilitado e o log é salvo no Sistema de Arquivos.

Em relação à conta de armazenamento eu avaliei os logs, e os logs que tem batem com os logs gerados pelo meu sistema todos em camada fria. Abaixo segue métricas de utilização da conta de armazenamento.

[image: Utilização da conta de armazenamento, marcação no dia 15 quando segundo relatório de custos começou ter consumo elevado de gravação]

Dia 16 segundo a análise de custos foi quando houve um volume de gravação elevado, mas daqui não consigo saber onde e por qual origem se deu esse volume de operações, pois no meu entendimento segundo o gráfico anterior de consumo, dia 16 quase não houve operações de gravação em relação ao período como um todo.

Onde consigo identificar estas operações? pois no dia 16 não existem logs de blob:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de muito batalhar a resposta que tive da Microsoft foi que arquivos com taxa de acesso alta de leitura serão considerados como "quente" mesmo que esteja na camada "fria".

Apesar de estranho essa foi a única resposta congruente que recebi.